# How to make a static site made with Backbone respond to dynamic urls to the site

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I am making a static site with Backbone that will have only one file as an entry point(index.html). I was wondering how to make the site respond to any *external* url to the site? For example

www.example.com/this_route
www.example.com/search

While I do have a router set up now, I can only trigger url changes from within the app:

```
router.navigate( "to_here" );
```

But if i type www.example.com/to_here in the url bar of a browser, i get the error: "The requested URL /to_here was not found on this server."

Thanks for any help

Comment: *"While I do have a router set up now"* please mention the details of your setup so that we can understand what's wrong/provide suggestions. What http server are you using to serve `index.html` at the moment..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up your web server to always respond with `index.html`.

I'm using [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/) for this purpose with rules below, it always serve index.html for any requests like this `localhost:8080/to_here`

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /path/to/folder/with/files;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh interesting, thanks. I imagine I could do the same with apache?

Comment: I haven't worked with Apache, sorry. Also do not forget to allow server to handle requests to .js, .css and other resources.

Comment: @bleepbloop i have your intended functionality set up with apache tomcat. You need to set up a filter to catch all requests and reroute them accordingly. Let all asset/ajax requests go thru, and reroute everything else back to index.html

Answer (score 1):

In Backbone you "catch" the url from the browser when they starts with "#". So, even your Router is something like this:

```
routes : {
          "this_route":"exampleFunction",
          "search":"searchFunction"
      }
```

if you want to execute each function depending on the browser url, you have to write **www.example.com#this_route** or **www.example.com#search** to fire the functions with Router.js